# How to copy code from a text file to a .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, copy-paste

I am making a hardcoded voice assistant and I want others to be able to use it as I do i.e. open applications and other stuff but the paths have my username in them so I am thinking I should create a txt file with all the voice commands (in python syntax) and make a script that copies the contents of txt file to a py file, so that others can copy paste and add more commands simply by editing the txt file.

How do I do it? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: yes ... simpler way is to read the config data from the txt file ... copying to a py file seems pointless

Comment: A Python script file **is** a text file. Just have others save the file with that extension.

Comment: That's way easier than my method. Thanks for the help you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("filetowrite.py","wb") as fout:
    with open("filetoread.txt","rb") as fin:
         fout.write(fin.read())
```

I guess ... seems like a strange method to use to me though

Comment: I am a noob in coding. I don't know the better alternative. If there's a better way than please do tell me. I am currently using the method told by jsotola and martineau i.e. changing the extension of the file. Thanks for helping